# How to have Beamer theorems NOT in box?

Tags: beamer, boxes

I'm trying to create a theorem style using Beamer with Madrid theme, but I can't figure out how to not have it in boxes. Everything I try just simply ends up automatically inside boxes. Also, I don't want a line break between the title and the text. 
Any ideas? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain what you *do* want the theorem style to look like.

Comment: It would also be helpful to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want, easier for people to help you since they have some code to start from and much more likely that they will actually try to help you.

Comment: Type it directly inside the frame environment ?

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the definition of theorems in beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
%  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}% removed
  {%
    \inserttheoremname
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
    \space% new
  }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{A theorem in a box}
        \begin{theorem}
         Let $r, s$ be integers such that gcd$(r, s)=1$. 
        Given integers $a,b$, there exists unique 
        $x <rs$ such that 
        \end{theorem} 
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]