# Simple Beamer Template

Tags: beamer, templates, document-classes

How can I change the Beamer to the simplest class? For example, the text is black and the background is white like the follows
[image]
[image: r]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there already is a read-to-use theme in this style, but you could approximate it with a couple of settings like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=black]{structure}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}


\title{Title}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{\insertshorttitle\hfill\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329929/36296
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
%  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}% removed
  {%
    {\bfseries\inserttheoremname
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi}%
    \space% new
  }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{A theorem in a box}
        \begin{theorem}
         Let $r, s$ be integers such that gcd$(r, s)=1$. 
        Given integers $a,b$, there exists unique 
        $x <rs$ such that 
        \end{theorem} 
        \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]